# Django Form Resubmission on Refresh even after Redirecting

Tags: python, django, redirect, post

I have a page (corresponding to the detail view) displaying a list of items, each with an associated check box. There is a button on the page which when submitted adds to request.POST the list of checked items, and signifies that they should be deleted. Upon deletion, I want to redirect back to the same view - detail.

First two lines of the detail view:

```
def detail(request, inventory_id, category_id=None):
    check_POST_and_update(request, inventory_id, category_id)
```

Here is the relevant part of the check_POST_and_update method.

```
def check_POST_and_update(request, inventory_id=None, category_id=None):
    if request.method=='POST' and request.user.is_authenticated():
        r = request.POST

        if r.get('delete_items', None) and r.get('select_item', None):
        for item_id in r.getlist('select_item'):
            Item.objects.get(pk=item_id).delete()
        return redirect('inventory:detail', inventory_id, category_id)
```

The deletion and redirect seem to be working fine. I select a few items, click on the "Delete selected items" button and the same page is returned, with the selected items now gone from the list. However, if I then refresh the page at this point, I get "DoesNotExist ... Item matching query does not exist". ie the old POST object is being resubmitted. I can confirm this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'select_item': [u'149'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'MASoSxSn2hmwgFKf95WcWjnVa6GYUnPe'], u'delete_items': [u'Delete selected items']}>
```

Why is this happening? I thought that the redirect method was supposed to prevent this sort of problem. How can I fix the code to make sure that the old POST object does not get resubmitted when refreshing the page?

Thanks in advance and sincere apologies if I have made a silly error somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the response from `check_POST_and_update` in the `detail` view, so the view will continue to be processed and will eventually return a different response.

Normally you would do `return check_POST_and_update`, but I don't think that will work, because I think there's a bit of the `detail` view that you haven't shown.

You could check the result of the method before returning it as follows :

```
def detail(request, inventory_id, category_id=None):
    response = check_POST_and_update(request, inventory_id, category_id)
    if response is not None:
        return response 
   ...
```

I don't like this approach, it seems quite hacky. The code might be easier to understand if you return a boolean from the `check_POST_and_update` method, and generate the response in the main view.

Comment: Thanks! You're right - it solved the problem. I'm now looking into ways to refactor the code to make it less "hack".